# How do I sort char arrays by numbers in them

Tags: arrays, sorting, char

I was given something of a home task to do for my c++ OOP class.

I'm stuck at this part that requires me to sort an array of type "Student" which is a class, by it's char * studentID attribute. The ID has the following format: "IBXXXXXX" X being a number.

How do I sort this array of objects by this attribute? Not sure how to compare the numbers in a  char array.

Example data:
IB140116
IB130115
IB130114

I need to get:
IB130114
IB130115
IB140116

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not that familiar with C++ but since the ID will always consist of 6 digits you could simply loop over the digits from left to right and compare them. As soon as one digit has a higher value than the other, the ID will be greater. If the two digits are the same value go on to the next digit. If no digit is left: Two IDs are equal.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort it by the number, to convert it you can use this function:

```
int StringToNumber(char *str)  // for example str = IB123456
{
    if (str != nullptr)
    {
        str += 2;              // str now is 123456
        return std::stoi(str); // returns 123456 in the format of int   
    }
    return 0;
}
```